# how to convert network to host address in tcl

Tags: tcl

convert this code in tcl and how to make a function network to host in tcl

```
capturedTlpData[i] = (UInt32)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32((byte[])retValbuffer,i*4));
```

here NetworkToHostOrder is:-
`

```
public static int NetworkToHostOrder(int network`)
```

Comment: answer fast please

Comment: There's generally no need to do this in tcl because tcl accepts network address as dotted decimal strings. What exactly is your use case?

Comment: then what should i do to do  the same thing in tcl?

Comment: can u please tell the conversion

Comment: Usually there's no conversion. Again I have to ask, what's your use case? Do you want to save binary 32 bit integer into a file or send it over the network? Is there any reason why text is not good enough?

Comment: i have to send it over network

Comment: please answer it fast

Comment: I think you have a syntax error in the parameter declaration `int network\``. The `\`` is probably not be allowed in a variable name in whatever language you're writing in (doesn't look like Tcl).

Answer (score 1):

You've read four bytes from the network in network-endian form and want to convert it to an unsigned integer? The `binary scan` command can do that. You'll want the `u` modifier, which requires Tcl 8.6.

```
binary scan $theBytes Iu theValue
```

For example, if you have the bytes that correspond to the ASCII `abcd` then you get:

```
set theBytes "abcd"
binary scan $theBytes Iu theValue
puts $theValue
# Prints 1633837924
puts [format %x $theValue]
# Prints 61626364
```

If you're using Tcl 8.5, just use the `I` specifier and post-process the value with this to convert to unsigned (because Tcl uses bignums internally):

```
set theValue [expr {$theValue & 0xFFFFFFFF}]
```

Comment: Going the other way will use `binary format`. “Network ordering” is big endian.